# Does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{2n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

So far, I have applied the root test to find that it is inconclusive since $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=1$.  I suppose it may be conditionally convergent then but not absolutely convergent. Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: "...conditionally...": All of the terms are positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** You can use a familiar limit to show that the terms do not have limit $0$, so our series diverges.

Comment: Further hint:   Look at the limit of the reciprical of the terms, then from that infer that the terms go to the reciprical of that limit, since the reciprical functin is continuous